# Layouts in angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui

I am trying to develop a simple directive which can take a option of layout configuration.

Lets say i want to render something like this on the page

### I want to render this 4 co-ordinates in one directive, which can then render directive1, in 1 and directive 2 in 2, directive 3 in 3 and directive 4 in 4

```
       1    |      3
            |
------------|----------------
            |      4
     2      |
            |
```

Any ideas?

Note, i can statically render, the page without any issues, question is how do we render this dynamically, like..how an example directive would look like?

Thank you.

Comment: So you won't consider solutions which are not creative enough?

Comment: Come on mate,  i never said that.

Comment: @user1224036 I confirm with @ Stevie, you indeed said "as creative as possible please"

Comment: ok apologies, i have edited post, removed the line, now please can we get on with answers?

Comment: @user1224036 Before we take advantage of our creativity, we want to know what you have tried. Please show what you have done so we can improve it together.

Comment: ok i am going through the miglayout http://www.miglayout.com/ stuff, and i think we can difine *layout.html which would then render me what i want? in this case my html name would be fourquadrantLayout.html, i can also say from server side ..my key to the page to be rendered is fourquadrant